# Render p:selectManyCheckbox with 10 columns

Tags: jsf, primefaces, multiple-columns, selectmanycheckbox

I developed an interface JEE / JSF for some statistics.
I created checkbox to select references that the user wishes to display, but the trouble is that I use to generate the checkbox Arraylist based on data from my database.

And I can not position them as I want. I wish that after 10 checkbox, others generates directly to the line etc. ..

I have this result

[image: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2013/48/1385458240-after.jpg]

And i wish i could do this

[image]

MTBFBEAN

```
private List<String> selectedReference = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> listReference = new ArrayList<String>(); 
private Boolean afficher = false; // Déclaration du bool pour le rendered de
                                    // ma vue dans MTBF

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public StatisticsBeanMTBF() {
    this.beginDate = new Date(2001, 00, 01);
    List<ProductConfModel> listtmp = this.moduleGlobal.getProductConfModels(2);
    for (ProductConfModel pcm : listtmp) {

        this.listReference.add(pcm.getReference());
        }
    }

public void mTBFByType() {
    this.afficher = true;
    this.listMTBF = new ArrayList<StatistiquesMTBF>();
    List<StatistiquesMTBF> suspense = this.moduleGlobal.getMTBFByType(nbHeure, nbJour, NS, DAE, beginDate, endDate);
    for (StatistiquesMTBF smtbf : suspense) {
        for (String s : this.selectedReference) {
            if (smtbf.getReference().equals(s)) {
                this.listMTBF.add(smtbf);
            }
```

JSF XHTML

```
    <h:outputText value="Date début :* " />
                    <p:calendar value="#{statisticsBeanMTBF.beginDate}"
                        navigator="true" required="true" />
                    <h:outputText value="Date fin:* " />
                    <p:calendar value="#{statisticsBeanMTBF.endDate}" navigator="true"
                        required="true" />

                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <h:outputText value="Selectionner votre référence : " />

                    <p:selectManyCheckbox id="grid" columns="5"
                        value="#{statisticsBeanMTBF.selectedReference}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{statisticsBeanMTBF.listReference}" />
                        </p:selectManyCheckbox> 
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:separator />
```

If anyone can help me it would be nice.

Thank you !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I get this outcome using:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="selection">
    <p:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection" value="#{selection.selection}">
</h:panelGroup>
```

and setting each `<tr>`:

```
.selection tr {
   float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
```

In your case set it to 10% and outer container to `width: 100%`.

**It looks like that:**

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, but I'm 4.0 primefaces, your tags <h: this is not the primefaces.

Comment: The fact you are using PrimeFaces doesn't mean you can't use plain JSF tags. I'm also using PF4.0 and yet..

Comment: Just switched to `<p:selectManyCheckbox>` and the outcome is the same!

Comment: Thank you Kuba it works perfectly! Thank you all for the time you spent to help me!

Comment: .selection td {
   float: left;
    width: 33%;
}   //worked me

Answer (score 5):

You should add `layout="grid"` to your `p:selectManyCheckbox` according to this [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectManyCheckbox.jsf). Like this :

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="grid" layout="grid" columns="5" value="#{statisticsBeanMTBF.selectedReference}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{statisticsBeanMTBF.listReference}" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

**EDIT :**

A fast search in PrimeFaces documentations show that `columns` was added in the version 4.0. If you doesn't have this version or can't upgrade, you'll need to do it the old way with some CSS.

Comment: It should. It's helpful to mention PF version and elaborate "doesn't work" in more detail.

Comment: Hi BalusC, I use primefaces 4.0.

Comment: Alexandre Lavoie : Look at my JSF, I am 4.0 and I tried the columns

Comment: Apparently you're not a actually using 4.0. Likely your runtime classpath is dirty.

Comment: Thanks is a excelent solution :)